# Generate multiple dates from age segments

Tags: r, date, lubridate

Current code:

Here I give the different segments; 0-20 years old, 21-45 years old, 46-65 years old and 66-100 years old.

```
dob020 <- seq(today() - years(20), today(), by = "day")
dob2145<- seq(today() - years(45), today() - years(20), by = "day")
dob4665 <- seq(today() - years(65), today() - years(40), by = "day")
dob66100 <- seq(today() - years(100), today() - years(65), by = "day")
```

Here I want to generate the random DoB's based on a given probabilty. Years 0-20 must have a probabilty of 15%, 21-45 40% etc.

```
dateofbirth <-  sample(c(sample(dob020, 1), sample(dob2145, 1), 
sample(dob4665, 1), sample(dob66100, 1)), 10, replace = TRUE, 
prob = c(0.15,0.40, 0.35, 0.10))
```

This kind of works fine, except now the result I get is 4 different date of births (one from each segment) and they are spread across the 10 results.

The result I want is 10 different date of births that still take the probabilty in to account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in one `sample`, you need to sample them separately and then combine them

```
n <- 100
prob <- c(0.15,0.40, 0.35, 0.10)

c(sample(dob020, n*prob[1]), sample(dob2145, n*prob[2]), 
      sample(dob4665, n*prob[3]), sample(dob66100, n*prob[4]))
```